# Upload multiples files with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to post two different types of files on two different fields into my database. I've been looking for the answer on the entire Stack Overvlow, but I still couldn't find it.

This is my controller:

```
public function insertLamaran()
{
 $pas_foto = ($_FILES['pas_foto']['name']);
 $cv = ($_FILES['cv']['name']);
if ($pas_foto !== "")
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['log_threshold'] = 1;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
    $config['max_size'] = '100000'; // 0 = no file size limit
    $config['file_name']='smallImage.jpg';
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('pas_foto');
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $data['pas_foto'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
   }

   if ($cv !== "")
   {
                    $config['file_name']='bigImage.pdf';
                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
                    $config['max_size'] = '100000'; // 0 = no file size limit
                    $config['overwrite'] = false;
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->do_upload('filename1');
                    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                    $data['cv'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
    }

    $data['u_id'] = $this->input->post('u_id');
    $this->M_upload->insertLamaran($data);
}
```

and this is my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('Upload/insertLamaran')?>" method="post">
    <input hidden type="text" name="u_id" value="<?php echo ucfirst($this->session->userdata('u_id')); ?>"></input><br>
    <div class="row wowload fadeInLeftBig">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <label for="pasfoto">Pas Foto (.jpg)</label>
        <input id="pas_foto" type="file" name="pas_foto" multiple="true">
        <label for="CV">CV (.pdf)</label>
        <input id="cv" type="file" name="cv" multiple="true">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form
```

the errors said that

> Undefined index: pas_foto. Filename: controllers/Upload.php Line Number: 22

Does anybody know what's happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i seen you correct form type so answer for pdf file
you forgot to add pdf file name

change this

```
$this->upload->do_upload('filename1');
```

into this

```
$this->upload->do_upload('cv');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, load `url` helper in your controller's `constructor`. I think your view file must be like this.Need to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for file uploading.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('upload/insertLamaran');?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input hidden type="text" name="u_id" value="<?php echo ucfirst($this->session->userdata('u_id')); ?>"></input><br>
    <div class="row wowload fadeInLeftBig">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <label for="pasfoto">Pas Foto (.jpg)</label>
        <input id="pas_foto" type="file" name="pas_foto" multiple="true">
        <label for="CV">CV (.pdf)</label>
        <input id="cv" type="file" name="cv" multiple="true">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks , maaas! but now, the problem is.. only the image who success uploaded.. not the pdf..